# Redirect connection to different port on other IP?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

When someone makes a connection to myIP:123, I'd like my server (Ubuntu) to redirect their connection to otherIP:456. Connections to other ports should obviously be treated normally. I'm pretty sure this would be done with iptables, I just have no idea what the rule would be. I know how I would do it as an HTTP redirect, but this isn't HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 123 -j DNAT --to-destination otherserver:456
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

this however implies that you have IP forwarding turned on in sysctl 
ie. `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Answer (score 0):

you can use iptables to redirect port/ip.

examples are given here:

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables

or you can install rinetd, which i think is easier, in my opinion. i usually use rinetd.